# kafka is synchronized when send Message

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How to know when ack = all, when sending messages, kafka is synchronized or not in java?

```
public KafkaProducer<String, String> createProducer(String ack) {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaConstant.KAFKA_BROKER);
    props.put("acks",ack );

    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    return producer;
}
```

and  method send:

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, content)
```

and final

```
  KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = mainService.createProducer(ack);
    RecordMetadata recordMetadata = mainService.sendKafkaMessage(key, content, producer, topic)
```

Comment: What's your implement of `mainService.sendKafkaMessage `? Only we know how you implent this mehod can we know it synchronized or not.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka client is asynchronous unless `producer.send(...).get` is invoked. Follow the kafka client documentation for better understanding.

Kafka has buffering and batching at client side which also decides when the messages will be delivered to brokers. Also it depends on the producer configs set at client side.